# SharePoint 2013 with Calendar email?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, domain, cross-domain

I have connected a simple Calendar in SharePoint 2013 with my Outlook, however, I would like for it to accept incoming email and automatically accept meeting invitations to display on the SharePoint Calendar.

I have already got this working but from what I can see it will ONLY accept emails from within the same domain name. My work has a separate domain name on a separate server which does not seem to work. Is there any way to open up the connection for the SharePoint Calendar to accept all incoming email from any domain, or at least add another domain???

Comment: did you add your server into relay that they can accept the email from different domains?

Comment: Yes the relay I set to accept all except the list below, with nothing specified to be blocked. I believe it should work. Is it because the server is an intranet site and the domain is not connecting to the internet??

Comment: another thing u should try is, send an alert /email to that domain email id which is not working...to check if really sharepoint send the emails to that address. All your sharepoint server are in the relay?